# Rails Active Record Query joins only, any

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

```
Student has_many :enrollments
```

With this query I see those students that have `true` enrollments, but also those that have **both**, `true` and `false` enrollments:

```
@students = Student.joins(:enrollments).where(enrollments: { is_active: false })
```

Is there some "only" attribute that I can add to see students that have **only** active enrollments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way straightforward would be to find the students that inactive enrolments and then explicitly exclude them. Something like:

```
have_inactives = Enrollment.where(is_active: false).select(:student_id)
@students      = Student.joins(:enrollments).where.not(id: have_inactives)
```

The `joins(:enrollments)` will filter out `Student` entries that don't have any enrolments and the `where.not(...)` will exclude all those students that have inactive enrolments (using a subquery so all the work will still be inside the database where it belongs).

---

BTW, you might want to fix your spelling of "enrolment", the double-l misspelling will probably end up driving you or someone other programmer crazy.