# rails controller find record with no associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

```
Student has_many enrollments
```

Is there a way to see only students that have **no** enrollments?

Something like:

```
@students = Student.includes(:enrollments).where(Enrollment.none? })
```

Comment: A simple adaptation of my answer to your other recent question would solve this. Do you understand how my other answer works?

Comment: here I don't understand the controller syntax, how to check for Enrolments... something like: `@student = Student.joins(:enrollments).where.not(id: any?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adapt my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41496662/479863) and say "give me the students whose `id`s don't appear in the enrolments table" like this:

```
enrolled  = Enrollment.select(:student_id)
@students = Student.where.not(:id => enrolled)
```

That will use a subquery inside the database.

An alternative is to do a LEFT JOIN and look for rows that didn't satisfy the join condition:

```
Student.joins('left join enrollments on students.id = enrollments.student_id')
       .where(:enrollments => { :id => nil })
```